# In search of a preprint by Litherland

Tags: reference-request

I've seen the following citation a lot: "R. LITHERLAND: A formula for the Casson-Gordon invariants of a knot, preprint." I can't seem to find a corresponding publication. [Added in edit: apparently the paper never appeared in print.] Does anyone have access a copy?

Thanks!

Comment: it seems that preprint is superseded by http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0007088

Comment: Did you ask the author for a copy? He's not that hard to find.